# Python openpyxl comment shape property

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to set properties of comments (mainly the shape) in excel by openpyxl, but I cannot find examples. I'd like to set it with something like:

```
ws.cell(column = x, row = y).comment.NEEDED_METHOD_HERE = ...
```

If you have good examples or any idea what is the exact method, please share it with me, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently (2016) cannot be done with openpyxl and may never be possible.

Comment: But for example there is "add_comment_shape" function in "\openpyxl-2.4.0b1-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\comments\shape_writer.py", it looks like it can be done somehow.

Comment: Yes, but there's no real intelligence in it. The VML used is essentially undocumented and deprecated.

Comment: Charlie Clark: Thank you for your reply. To sum it up, I wanted to use openpyxl to preserve template style after writing, but I have found win32com module also do the job and can set comment shape, too (what I've already used). And xlrd - xlwt doesn't preserve template styles if I am right.

Comment: You can't use xlwt to edit files and in any case it only supports the old `.xls` format. You might want to look at using xlwings instead of win32com. If Microsoft ever switches to using DrawingML for comments then you'll get the chance to do what you want.

Comment: I could solve comment formatting by win32com and it seems xlwings cannot do that (add comment and set shape), but it looks interesting, thanks for the idea, it can be useful for other things.